# How to extract first occurance of one value using powerscript

Tags: powershell

I have one xml file , it has few occurrence of `DSCID="cbbfa194-54de-4b81-932f-eaacfc593e12"` entry.

I want to extract the first occurrence of `DSCID` i.e `cbbfa194-54de-4b81-932f-eaacfc593e12` and assign it to a variable for further use.
I am unable to get the result. I was trying the following syntax.

```
(Select-String -Path "C:\xxx.xml" -Pattern "DSCID=(.*)").Matches.Groups[0]
```

But as a result I am getting all the lines after `DSCID`.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your XML file? As the source is an XML file, you can parse nodes with XML operations and not string operations

Comment: <DistributionService XSWebAdress="" DSCID="cbbfa194-54de-4b81-932f-eaacfc593e12" LogLevel="Normal" IsPublisher="true" MaxSimultaneousQvb="4" MaxSimultaneousReaderQVBs="20" IsCluster="true" SectionAccessUserName="cKPAttgM+lQ=" SectionAccessPassword="cKPAttgM+lQ=" CPUAffinity="1" CPUPriority="Low" ApplicationDataFolder="\\xxx\" Username="cKPAttgM+lQ=" Password="cKPAttgM+lQ=" DisableTaskTriggersForDocAdmins="false" ShowAlerts="true" ClusterName="XXXX" ModifiedByUser="" ModifiedTime="2018-04-12T03:12:05.2400338+01:00" ID="2311a84c-c419-4eb9-9295-1cb7baf2cf4b" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try was close, 
but to grep values in between double quotes you can't use double quotes around your RegEx

```
(Select-String -Path ".\xxx.xml" -Pattern 'DSCID="([^"]+)"').Matches.Groups[1].Value
cbbfa194-54de-4b81-932f-eaacfc593e12
```

To get all matches you will need a foreach

```
Select-String -Path ".\xxx.xml" -Pattern 'DSCID="([^"]+)"'|ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Comment: You will need to iterate the select-Object output with a ForEach to get **ALL** matches, so yes (just did a test on this).

Comment: @LotPings I'm pretty sure that Select-String is not the good solution for parsing XML files.

Comment: @Manu Agreed, but he doesn't want to parse an XML file, he just wants to grep one value. You are free to present a better XML conformant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Given your XML example you can retrieve your DSCID like this:

```
[XML]$xmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\xxx.xml"
$DSCID = $xmlDocument.DistributionService.DSCID
```

Comment: it is giving me empty value. Please see my sample source file.

Comment: So your XML file must have other levels of markup. You have to adapt the `$xmlDocument.DistributionService.DSCID` part to reflect the actual structure of your XML file. But glad that the other solution worked for you.

Comment: Here your code works with the sample data provided +1